# for loop on character variables

Tags: r

I have a data set having 3 columns `Part`, `Claimid` and `Cost`. The dataset looks as below:

```
Part  Claimid Cost
Part1 ID1 12
Part1 ID20 29
Part2 ID21 21
Part2 ID40 13
Part3 ID41 11
Part3 ID60 10
```

The cost column is a random number between 1 to 10
I am trying to run a loop for every `Part` (here 3 parts) and use dplyr package to create three distinct data frames

```
library(dplyr)
claimid <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)
plist <- unique(claimid$Part) ##Create the number of loops (Here 3)
for (i in plist) {
    plist <- claimid %>% select(Part,Claimid) %>% filter(Part %in% i)
}
```

I am getting the last 20 observations when I print plist because obviously R is saving the last observation of loop.

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a `list` to store the output if we are using the `for` loop.  It is better to keep the data.frames in a `list` and not as three separate data.frame objects.

```
plist <- unique(claimid$Part) 
lst <- setNames(vector("list", length(plist)), plist)
 for (i in seq_along(plist)) {
   lst[[i]] <- claimid %>%
                  select(Part,Claimid) %>% 
                  filter(Part %in% plist[i])
}
```

---

But, this can be done more directly with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(plist, function(nm) claimid %>%
                                      select(Part, Claimid) %>%
                                      filter(Part %in% nm)
                      )
```

---

However, if we need to create three different data.frame objects, `assign` is the option (but not recommended)

```
for (i in plist) {
       assign(i, claimid %>% select(Part,Claimid) %>% filter(Part %in% i))
  }


Part1
#   Part Claimid
#1 Part1     ID1
#2 Part1    ID20

Part2
#   Part Claimid
#1 Part2    ID21
#2 Part2    ID40

 Part3
#   Part Claimid
#1 Part3    ID41
#2 Part3    ID60
```

Comment: Many Thanks "akrun". I got to learn seq_along function and assign function. Thank you for helping beginners like me. God bless.

Comment: Hi akrun, If I use this code claimid <- read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(Part = character(),totcost = integer(),claim = integer(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
plist <- unique(claimid$Part)
for (i in plist) {
  assign(i, claimid %>% filter(Part %in% i) %>% group_by(Part) %>% summarise(totcost = sum(Cost),
                                                                             claim = n_distinct(Claimid)))
  rbind(df,i)
} Would I be able to append the datasets Part1, Part2 and Part3 together in a single dataset df?

Comment: @ARIMITRAMAITI  If you started with a single dataset, I am not sure why you are splitting it to different datsets.